# Massive photons and gauge invariance

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, mass, polarization, gauge-invariance

When trying to quantize Maxwell's equations
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}=0,
\end{equation}
one takes into account gauge invariance
\begin{equation}
A^{\mu}(x) \rightarrow A^{\mu}(x)+ \partial \Lambda(x).
\end{equation}
From this gauge, we know that mass terms are forbidden in the Lagrangian and thus photons are massless. this is clear to me.

However, Nobel laureate M. Veltman says: Due to this gauge choice, we have unphysical photons in the formalism that cannot be observed. Thus we choose to give photons a little mass in order for the Lagrangian not to be gauge invariant anymore and thus getting rid of all unphysical photons.

Further, in order to recover the 2 states of polarization for the photons, we must cancel out two of the 4 components of $A^{\mu}(x)$. One is done by the Coulomb gauge
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{A}=0,
\end{equation}
which is a standard procedure to do in QFT. The second state we want to remove is due to the scalar function $\Lambda(x)$, which has the property:
\begin{equation}
 \partial^{\mu}  \partial_{\mu} \Lambda(x)=0.
\end{equation}
Now, all redundancies are removed and we recover 2 states of polarization. Again, M.Veltman uses a different method to get rid of the latter redundant. He takes the limit of the mass to zero and recovers two states of polarization. I think both ways have same physical meaning, but I don't see the connection

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Link to Veltman? Which page?

Comment: isn't it forbidden for photons to have a mass due to gauge invariance of the Lagrangian?

Comment: My reference is: Diagrammatica: The Path to Feynman diagrams. page 11

Comment: I think he's just regulating an infrared divergence.